# Loading items to a extendable list view using adapter

Tags: android, adapter, android-viewholder

Im trying to transfer data between 2 activities and then display using a adapter. Earlier I have used same adapter to display List, but this gives couple of errors in my adapter and i have showed them in my code below.

Can anyone figure what should i do to correct it. any help would be appreciated.

1st activity passing these details,

```
                                intent.putExtra("quantity", quantity);
                                intent.putExtra("instructions", instructions);
                                intent.putExtra("subTotal", subTotal);
                                intent.putExtra("description", description);
                                intent.putExtra("price", price);
```

2nd activity

```
        String quantity = getIntent().getStringExtra("quantity");
        String description = getIntent().getStringExtra("description");
        String subTotal = getIntent().getStringExtra("subTotal");
        String price = getIntent().getStringExtra("price");

        CustomGridPastaCart adapter = new CustomGridPastaCart(getApplicationContext(),
                quantity, description, subTotal, price); //error2
```

CustomGridPastaCart, BaseAdapter

```
public class CustomGridPastaCart extends BaseAdapter {
private Context context;
List<Item> items;

public CustomGridPastaCart(Context c, List<Item> items) {
    this.items = items;
}

public CustomGridPastaCart(Context applicationContext, String quantity, //it was forcing me to generate this error2 in above
        String description, String subTotal, String price) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return items.size();
}

@Override
public Item getItem(int position) { //here i had to change object to Item because it gave an error1 in below
    return items.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(
            R.layout.cart_activity, parent, false);
        holder.tvHeader = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.lblListHeader);
        holder.tvUnitprice = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.lbl_unitprice);
        holder.tvQty = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lbl_qty);
        holder.ivSubtotal = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.lblsubtotal);
        convertView.setTag(holder);

    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    // Get item...
    Item item = getItem(position); //error1 here

    // Set values.
    holder.tvHeader.setText(item.description);
    holder.tvUnitprice.setText(item.price);
    holder.tvQty.setText(item.quantity);
    holder.ivSubtotal.setText(item.subTotal);

    return convertView;
}

private class ViewHolder {
   private TextView tvHeader;
   private TextView tvUnitprice;
   private TextView tvQty;
   private TextView ivSubtotal;
```

}
}

Item.java

```
public class Item {
    String quantity;
    String description;
    String subTotal;
    String price;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are using the adapter wrong. A ListView needs an Adapter which is basically a structure containing a list (or array), and methods to deal with it and create the view representing each item.

You are passing the fields for a single item, so `description`is a String and therefore this fails:

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return description.size(); //The method size() is undefined for the type String
}
```

There's the same problem with `getItem`

```
@Override
public Object getItem(int position) { 
    return description.get(position); //The method get(int) is undefined for the type String
}
```

You need to implement something like this for your adapter:

```
public class CustomGridPastaCart extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context context;
    List<Item> items;

    public CustomGridPastaCart(Context c, List<Item> items) {
        this.items = items;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) { 
        return items.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(
                R.layout.cart_activity, parent, false);
            holder.tvHeader = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.lblListHeader);
            holder.tvUnitprice = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.lbl_unitprice);
            holder.tvQty = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lbl_qty);
            holder.ivSubtotal = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.lblsubtotal);
            convertView.setTag(holder);

        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        // Get item...
        Item item = getItem(position);

        // Set values.
        holder.tvHeader.setText(item.description);
        holder.tvUnitprice.setText(item.price);
        holder.tvQty.setText(item.quantity);
        holder.ivSubtotal.setText(String.valueOf(item.subTotal));

        return convertView;
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
       private TextView tvHeader;
       private TextView tvUnitprice;
       private TextView tvQty;
       private TextView ivSubtotal;
   }
}
```

And Item class:

```
public class Item {
    String quantity;
    String description;
    double subTotal;
    String price;
}
```

---

Test:

```
String quantity = getIntent().getStringExtra("quantity");
String description = getIntent().getStringExtra("description");
String subTotal = getIntent().getStringExtra("subTotal");
String price = getIntent().getStringExtra("price");

Item item = new Item();
item.quantity = quantity;
item.description = description;
item.subTotal = subTotal;
item.price = price;

ArrayList<Item> list = new ArrayList<Item>();
list.add(item);

CustomGridPastaCart adapter = new CustomGridPastaCart(getApplicationContext(), list);
```

Comment: i got a error in this line Item item = getItem(position);
Type mismatch: cannot convert from Object to Item

Comment: in this line,  holder.ivSubtotal.setText(item.subTotal); ------ The method setText(CharSequence) in the type TextView is not applicable for the arguments (double)

Comment: Yep, it's a double. Convert it into a String. I'll update the answer.

Comment: can u check my edited question. i have updated to my latest code. and i got 2 errors and i overcome them. but can u take a look at error 1 and 2. im not sure about the way i coreccted the error 2. can u check n tell me where i have gone wrong

Comment: The problem is that the parameters you are passing to your adapter constructor don't fit the actual constructor. There is something I'm missing: you use a list to display list of items. Is that what you need? If you look at the adapter constructor, it receives a list of items. Each item has `quantity, description, subTotal, price`, but you are passing, through extras, just one of each field. Could you post a screenshot or schema of your list to check how you want to display data?

Comment: I have added a screen shot

Comment: It's a bit confusing. Anyway, try the code I added to my answer. It's a list with just one item.

Comment: this didnt work but i used different adapter and i was able to load only the description. thaks alot for ur help :)